# Alfresco upload through REST

Tags: rest, upload, alfresco

I am using a RESTful API for uploading files to Alfresco Share. By using the noderef I can upload files. Is there any way to upload files by folder name?

In our application I have folder called Testing under testing. I have a sub folder called test 1, test 2 etc. This test1 and test2 is generated in Alfresco whenever user registers application by using the Alfresco REST API. But looking up the noderef and nodeid everytime is not a good deal. Could you please provide any feasible solution with sample code for uploading and downloading files by path.

Comment: Which RESTful API are you using? CMIS? The RESTful API that Share also uses? Something else?

Comment: i am using alfresco share not CMIS

Answer (score 8):

The parameters you need are available on the Alfresco upload script.

```
POST /alfresco/service/api/upload
```

- `destination` (the folder NodeRef where the node will be created)
- `updateNodeRef` (the NodeRef of an existing node that will be updated)
- `siteid` and `containerid` (the Site name and the container in that site where the document will be created)
- `uploaddirectory` - name of the folder (either in the site container or the destination) where the document will be uploaded. This folder must already exist

In this case you want to use `siteid`, `containerid`, and `uploaddirectory`. So say I had a site called `test` with a folder called `test1` I would set `siteid` to `test`, `containerid` to `documentLibrary`, and `uploaddirectory` to `test1`. The `uploaddirectory` should be able to handle your subdirectories.

Here is an example with curl:

```
curl --form "filedata=@test.txt" \
     --form siteid=test \
     --form containerid=documentLibrary \
     --form uploaddirectory=test1 \
      http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload?alf_ticket=<your ticket>
```

Comment: @tsting Provided an example with curl.

Comment: byte[] buff = getBytes("C:\\hi.jpg");
 MultiValueMap<String, Object> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
 FileSystemResource rsc = new FileSystemResource(
  "C:\\hi.jpg");
 request.add("filedata", rsc);
 request.add("siteid", "test");
 request.add("containerid", "documentLibrary");
 request.add("uploaddirectory", "test1");
 restTemplate.postForEntity(
  "http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload?alf_ticket="=<my ticket>"
    request, String.class);                                                              i tried above above code it showing http 404 error...

Comment: @tsting Silly question, but youre replacing the <your ticket> placeholder with the actual ticket right? The curl request above is correct and a 404 means it can't find the resource so you must not be locating the script correctly.

Comment: @Mardoz What to put as uploaddirectory if you want to upload to a subfolder further down the hierarchy? uploaddirectory=test1/subfolderX does not seem to work (even though existing). Web scripts returns a 404: message: "Cannot upload file since upload directory 'test1%2FsubfolderX/' does not exist."

Comment: @MathiasLin Works here. I can't help but think that your / is being escaped as the error I see for a bad path doesn't show the %2F. If you want to put the details of what you're doing up in another question I'll take a look.

Comment: @Mardoz I figured it out. I used the Chrome REST client for testing, which url-encoded the nodeRef. When I send it in raw mode, it's ok now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the out-of-the-box webscripts to upload and download files from the repository.

Webscript to upload a content - 
http://host:port/alfresco/service/cmissamples/upload

Webscript to get the content - http://host:port/alfresco/service/cmissamples/download

To know more about web script - https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts

Hope this helps.

Comment: This WIki page does not tell us anythin about these Web Script. How are they used?

Comment: I gave this link only to refer webscript not to use mentioned scripts. As they are OOTB we can directly call it through Javascript or java.

Comment: i am try to upload from java web applicatiion using rest api.So curl soiution not possible.Could you please provide sample code other than webscripts or curl

Comment: Hi, It's not possible for me to give example but this link will help you!!  https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/other-apis/uploading-file-alfresco-repository-using-alfrescorest-api

Answer (score 0):

MultipartFile multipartFile = docData.getBasicDetailsData().getUploadFile();
            File file11 = convert(multipartFile);

```
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9090/alfresco/s/cmissamples/upload");

        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 9090, "http");
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("admin", "admin"));
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        authCache.put(targetHost, new BasicScheme());
        final HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
        context.setAuthCache(authCache);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addBinaryBody("file", file11, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "file.ext");
        builder.addTextBody("name",multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        builder.addTextBody("path","/CAMUNDA");
        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        post.setEntity(multipart);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post,context);
        logger.info("response.toString(): "+response.toString());
```