# How to upload file to specifc folder Alfresco

Tags: python, alfresco

I'm trying out this and it works like a charm the file gets uploaded to the root folder.

```py
import json
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload"
auth = ("admin", "admin")
files = {"filedata": open("/tmp/foo.txt", "rb")}
data = {"siteid": "test", "containerid": "documentLibrary"}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, auth=auth)
print(r.status_code)
print(json.loads(r.text))
```

But how can I upload it to a specific folder? How do I define that and where?

I tired using `nodeid` but it did not work, any one got any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the noderef of the folder you want to upload to, or only the name?

Comment: I have have the noderef as well tired changing the documentLibary to that but it did not work, is ther some way it need to in like documentLibary\nordref number\ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alfresco upload through REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429957/alfresco-upload-through-rest)

Comment: You need to supply the `destination` parameter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431260/685641